# -[NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector error

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json

I have a simple php file that gives out the following *JSON* data:

```
{"a":"apple","b":"banana","c":"catnip"}
```

I've tried various ways to parse this data in iOS and simply give it out in an *NSLog*, for example like this:

```
 - (void) getData {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://bla.com/mapdata.php"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization 
                            JSONObjectWithData:data 
                            options:kNilOptions 
                            error:nil];

    NSLog(@"The size of json is %lu", (unsigned long)[json count]);

    for (int i = 0; i < json.count; i++) {
        NSDictionary *row = [json objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"a: %@, b:%@, c:%@", [row objectForKey:@"a"], [row objectForKey:@"b"], [row objectForKey:@"c"]);
    }
}
```

I always get the same fault in this line:

```
NSDictionary *row = [json objectAtIndex:i];
```

Error message: **-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1550a7d0**

Other answers to similar problems couldn't help me resolve the issue, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should really read the error message and trust it. Someone (your code) sends a message objectAtIndex to a dictionary. Therefore, something that you think is an array is actually a dictionary. What could that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON response is not an array, it contains an object. So you can't use

```
NSDictionary *row = [json objectAtIndex:i];
```

Just use:

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization 
                            JSONObjectWithData:data 
                            options:kNilOptions 
                            error:nil];
NSLog(@"a: %@, b:%@, c:%@", [json objectForKey:@"a"], [json objectForKey:@"b"], [json objectForKey:@"c"]);
```